# .net Remoting during Registering the specified System.MarshalByRefObject for sponsorship taking time around 2-4 min

Tags: c#, .net

I am facing one problem during Registering of MarshalByRefObject for sponsorship.
When calling **masterSponsor.Register(master)** for register then its taking around 2-4 min to register the MasterManager Object for sponsor. Don't know why its taking time.
Can any body help me why **Register** method of **ClientSponsor** class taking more time to register MarshalByRefObject for sponsor.

```
private MasterManager GetMasterManager()
    {
        Log.WriteLine(logSource, "GetMasterManager", LogLevel.Trace, 5);

        MasterManager master = null;

        // Check MasterManager register
        bool registered = false;
        WellKnownClientTypeEntry[] wkcte = RemotingConfiguration.GetRegisteredWellKnownClientTypes();
        foreach (WellKnownClientTypeEntry entry in wkcte)
        {
            if (entry.TypeName.Equals(MasterManagerType))
            {
                registered = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Create MasterManager remote instance
        if (!registered)
            RegisterMasterManager();
        if ((master = new MasterManager()) == null)
            throw new RemotingException("Remote object not found: MasterManager.");

        // Set Lifetime control for remote instance
        masterSponsor = new ClientSponsor(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(MasterManager.LifeTimeRenewal));

        masterSponsor.Register(master);

        // Set Lifetime control for remote events
        LifetimeServices.LeaseTime = TimeSpan.FromDays(90);
        LifetimeServices.RenewOnCallTime = TimeSpan.FromDays(90);

        return master;
    }



/// <summary>
        /// Register MasterManager in the Remoting infrastructure.
        /// </summary>
        private void RegisterMasterManager()
        {
            Log.WriteLine(logSource, ">>> RegisterMasterManager", LogLevel.Trace, 5);

            // Get configuration file full path
            string configFile = ConfigFolder + RemotingConfigurationFile;
            if (File.Exists(configFile))
            {
                // Configure Remoting from file
                RemotingConfiguration.Configure(configFile, false);
            }
            else
            {
                // Use Remoting default configuration
                Log.WriteLine(logSource, "Remoting configuration for Management not found. Using default.", LogLevel.Trace, 5);

                // Creating a custom formatter for a Channel sink chain.
                BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider clientProvider = new BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider();
                BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider serverProvider = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
                serverProvider.TypeFilterLevel = TypeFilterLevel.Full;

                // Creating the IDictionary to set the port on the channel instance.
                IDictionary channelProps = new Hashtable();
                channelProps["ref"] = "http";
                channelProps["port"] = 0;

                // Pass the properties for the port setting and the server provider in the server chain argument.
                HttpChannel channel = new HttpChannel(channelProps, clientProvider, serverProvider);

                // Register remote MasterManager
                ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);
                RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownClientType(typeof(MasterManager), MasterManagerDefaultUrl);
            }

            Log.WriteLine(logSource, "<<< RegisterMasterManager", LogLevel.Trace, 5);
        }
```

Comment: Have you profiled your code so you know exactly where the time is going? Which line is it hanging on? How long does it take your client machine to ping the server?

Comment: masterSponsor.Register(master) this line taking more time. it taking around 2-4 mins.

Comment: And if you ping the server from the client, do you get a quick response? Or does it take a long time to come back?

Comment: Both are on same machine.....